how to get specific cell value as int in google colab with python?
I have a google sheet from where I want to get value of a single cell as Integer.
Data is in Range(B5:D10) and I need to get value of Cell "C7" as an integer, which next I have to use in for loop as Stop value.
I have tried Pandas DataFrame, numpy approch, float technique but can't get single cell value useable in for loop. All these approaches return in series or list form that result in error.
What should be easy and useable code to get just single cell value as integer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

have you looked at the gspread lib? https://docs.gspread.org/en/v6.0.0/

https://docs.gspread.org/en/v6.0.0/user-guide.html#getting-a-cell-value

@Mayfair mrk = shI.acell('C7').value gives the cell value, but in str form. when i try to use it in for i in range(1,mrk): return error as
'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

https://pythonprinciples.com/blog/python-convert-string-to-int/#:~:text=To%20convert%20a%20string%20to%20an%20integer%2C%20use%20the%20built,an%20integer%20as%20its%20output.

@Mayfair  Now it is done. Thank you for your time.
